# Creating a dynamic array and then choosing highest value

Tags: java, android

I did some googling and didnt quite find what I was looking for. I have an app in which a user inputs values and when pressing calculate it will generate 64 values. My question is 2 parts.

1. How to do I capture these results and create a temporary array
2. How do I pick the largest value from the array and assign it to a double to use in a final equation in the app.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: my problem is right from the beginning... being new to programming i havent been able to find how to add output results into the array.

Comment: Have you written anything to read the user input? (Please click "[edit]" to post your code in your question.)

Comment: Yes I have code to read the user input.... the app generates the 64 results based on the user input. That part works great. i just need to capture the 64 answers and create an array from them in order to find the largest result. i need to use this result in one final equation.

Comment: Post the code where you generate the results, it's impossible to give you specific advice since there are too many ways to do this.

Comment: Here are 3 equations. I need to add Oytput_0, Output_1, Output_2 to an array and then grab the value that is the highest and assign that to a double so I can use it in an equation.

Output_0 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_0 * Cvalue_0) - (Avalue_0 * Avalue_0) );

Output_1 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_1 * Cvalue_1) - (Avalue_1 * Avalue_1) );

Output_2 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_2 * Cvalue_2) - (Avalue_2 * Avalue_2) );

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25472/discussion-between-kevin-m-and-sam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chat you wrote:

> Here are 3 equations. I need to add Oytput_0, Output_1, Output_2 to an array and then grab the value that is the highest and assign that to a double so I can use it in an equation.
>
> ```
>     Output_0 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_0 * Cvalue_0) - (Avalue_0 * Avalue_0) );
>     Output_1 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_1 * Cvalue_1) - (Avalue_1 * Avalue_1) );
>     Output_2 = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_2 * Cvalue_2) - (Avalue_2 * Avalue_2) );
> ```

Ok, try something like this:

```
Double[] outputs = new Double[3];
outputs[0] = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_0 * Cvalue_0) - (Avalue_0 * Avalue_0) );
outputs[1] = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_1 * Cvalue_1) - (Avalue_1 * Avalue_1) );
outputs[2] = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (Cvalue_2 * Cvalue_2) - (Avalue_2 * Avalue_2) );

Arrays.sort(outputs);
// Now outputs[2] will have the highest value. Use it however you please.
```

---

One note, I hope those three equations aren't three of *64* almost identical, hand-written equations.  Because if you store the `cValue_x`s in one array and the `aValue_x`s in another, then you can simply loop through *one* equation:

```
int count = Math.min(cValues.length, aValues.length);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    outputs[i] = temp1 + (temp2 / 2) - Math.sqrt( (cValues[i] * cValues[i]) - (aValues[i] * aValues[i]) );
```

Comment: the Cvalues are another entirely large equation. I had to do a break down cause the equation is quite extensive. I will try this out and see what i get and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an arraylist. It has the advantage that it is sortable. By default numeric values are sorted from low to high. So just use the last element of the list for your calculation. But it is up to you how to get your 64 precalculated values into this arraylist. I propose to buffer it, right after every single calculation.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
                    //i assume that you use doubles
        list.add(new Double(Math.random()*100));
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("highest value: " + list.get(63));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to create an array and fill it with the results:

`Double[] results = new Double[64];// (64 is the length of the array, the number of results)`

I don't know how you obtain the results, but I figure you store each result in a temporary variable (double_result):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    results[i] = double_result;
}
```

To pick the biggest value:

```
// Create a var with contains the biggest value
double max_value = 0;
// Compare all the values in the array with max_value, if its bigger store the new max value in max_malue
for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    if(results[i] > max_value){
        max_value = results[i];
    }
}
// Now in *max_value* you got the biggest value of the 64 results
```